# Why does singleton class survive Activity exit?

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton

I have a Singleton class which I use with the one of the activities of my application.

When I exit the activity - which brings me back to the menu activity - and then reopen the activity I find that when I try to access the singleton it is still the same.
Surely it should have been destroyed with the Activity?

I saw the question here: [living singleton, when activity end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619495/living-singleton-when-activity-end)
but could not quite follow what they mean.

When I press the return button on my device (or use finish within the Activity itself) is the Activity kept alive for future use? If so, then that would explain it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Surely it should have been destroyed with the Activity?

No.

> When I press the return button on my device (or use finish within the Activity itself) is the Activity kept alive for future use?

The activity is not. The *process* is. Singletons are part of the virtual machine and will live as long as the process does. Exiting the last activity does not immediately terminate the process, so the singleton lives on... at least for a while.

Android will eventually terminate that process to free up memory for other apps. How quickly it will do that depends on what the user is doing, what apps are installed, phase of the moon, etc.

Comment: Would that mean that if I made a call to the same singleton class from 2 different activities within my application then they would get the same one? I assume it was at Activity level.

Comment: The singleton concept defines that there should only ever be a single object instance of that class at a time, so yes they would get the same one unless somehow the activities were started in different virtual machines as a result of the system terminating the first one.

Comment: So best idea would be to destroy the singleton "manually" when exiting the Activity.

Comment: @theblitz If you're implementing a singleton then two different activities accessing the same instance of the singleton should be the desired effect. If they should be accessing different instances then you should just be using normal object instantiation.

Comment: I am using it only within one Activity. It has to be a singleton because it defines a pack of cards and I can't have more than one. The singleton class is referenced in a number of different classes withing the activity (not only in the main activity class itself).

Comment: @theblitz: "It has to be a singleton because it defines a pack of cards and I can't have more than one." -- that does *not* mean you need to follow the singleton pattern. Just make it a plain data member of your activity, please. Never make static data members unless absolutely necessary, and this case is not "absolutely necessary".

Comment: It's not a data object. It's a class that includes quite a few methods - a couple of hundred lines of code.

Comment: @theblitz: So? Do not make it a static data member. The ideal Java application has precisely zero static data members (other than primitives and strings declared `final`, which are effectively constants). If this object is only used within the scope of one `Activity`, it does not need to be a static data member, as everything else can access it from the `Activity` itself via the advanced programming technique called "a getter method". Hence, do not make it a static data member.

Comment: So what way to go if I need to reference the same instantiation from a number of different places?

Comment: @Commonsware, Google recommends static over virtual and recommends avoiding internal getters/setters. As can be read here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Comment: So, in theory, I could declare all the class as static.

Comment: @Will Kru: That refers to static methods and `static final` for constants.

Comment: @theblitz: "So what way to go if I need to reference the same instantiation from a number of different places?" -- you pass it as a parameter to a method. If you are new to Java, you should step back and learn Java.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know Java. :) Just that passing it all around is a big mess.Has to pass down through 3 or 4 levels of calls before getting to where I need it.